# How do I start a server before running a test suite in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

Problem is that if I do `test in Test <<= (taskA, taskB) { (A, B) => A doFinally B` or `test in Test := (taskB dependsOn taskA).value` and `taskA` is `forked`, then sbt execution doesn't continue to `taskB` and get's stuck indefinitely. It's caused by `doFinally/dependsOn`, because they probably makes it a single-threaded sequential execution. But I can't find any other way to order those 2 tasks, to make them run sequentially.

So far I've gotten this far :

```
lazy val startServer = taskKey[Unit]("Start PingPong Server before running Scala-JS tests")

lazy val jvm =
     project.in(file("jvm"))
        fork in (Test, runMain) := true
        startServer := {
          (runMain in Test).toTask(" com.example.PingPong").value
        }
      )

lazy val js =
    project.in(file("js"))
       test in Test <<= (startServer in Project("jvm", file("jvm")), test in(Test, fastOptStage)) {
         (startServer, test) => startServer doFinally test
       }
     )
```

The sbt execution stops on a task `startServer` that spawns a thread, even a daemon one. I tried `fork in startServer := true` but it didn't help.

I also tried `dependsOn`, but it also blocks :

```
test in Test := {
  (test in(Test, fastOptStage)).dependsOn(startServer in Project("jvm", file("jvm"))).value
}
```

If I do not start the server in the main class `PingPong`, it behaves as expected. Also if I do this, it works but it has a random order of execution and I don't know how to enforce it without `doFinally`.

```
test in Test := {
  (startServer in Project("jvm", file("jvm"))).value
  (test in(Test, fastOptStage)).value
}
```

I think I'm gonna have to try [sbt-sequential](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-sequential) or fork a new process.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of dealing with SBT I can suggest much more simple workaround. Create Class with static method to start server (it will check that server is not yet started), and in each test explicitly start this server. You'll need to set "fork in Test := true", to run server in separate JVM and shutdown it after tests finished.

I use this approach for starting Embedded Cassandra server for integration tests

In my case it's static method with Java, you can do the same with Scala and companion object.

```
  override def beforeAll() {
    log.info(s"Start Embedded Cassandra Server")
    EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra("/timeseries.yaml")
  }
```

and

```
public static void startEmbeddedCassandra(String yamlFile, String tmpDir) throws TTransportException, IOException, ConfigurationException {
        if (cassandraDaemon != null) {
            /* nothing to do Cassandra is already started */
            return;
        }

     // ... Start new server
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this too, I just need a way of starting that server from sbt via task from various other reasons ... It just needs to be forked, but sbt's fork just doesn't work, revolver does...

Comment: Also in this particular case, you can't do what you suggest because the `js` project is compiled to javascript and run on phantomJS and the jvm project has java dependencies. As I need to test the scalaJS project, I can't depend on the JVM project that has Java dependencies that won't compile to javascript :-) It's kinda messy

Answer (score 2):

For some reason none of these settings forks a new process :

```
fork := true
fork in runMain := true
fork in Test := true
fork in (Test, runMain) := true
```

That's why sequential `dependsOn/doFinally` blocks because the process is not forked...

I tried exactly the same with [revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) and it works. I recommend revolver to everybody who is trying to fork a process in sbt, because one can't rely the sbt's `fork` at least from this experience.

```
lazy val startServer = taskKey[Unit]("Start PingPong Server before running JS tests")

lazy val jvm =
     project.in(file("jvm"))
        mainClass in Revolver.reStart := Option("com.example.PingPong"),
        startServer := {
          (Revolver.reStart in Test).toTask("").value
        }
      )

lazy val js =
    project.in(file("js"))
       test in Test := (test in(Test, fastOptStage)).dependsOn(startServer in Project("jvm", file("jvm"))).value
     )
```